# Opening a Gstreamer Pipeline Fails in Opencv 3.1 But Works Fine in 3.2.. Why?

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

This is the pipeline:

```
const CAP_PIPELINE = 'filesrc location=$pipe' +
' ! video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream, width=800, height=448, framerate=30/1 ! h264parse ' + 
' ! omxh264dec ! videorate drop-only=true ! video/x-raw,framerate=4/1 ! videoconvert ! appsink';
```

the opencv code is basically:

```
VideoCapture cap
cap.open(pipeline)
```

This code works fine in Opencv 3.2, but in Opencv 3.1 it fails with this message in the Gstreamer log:

```
        gstbasetransform.c:1346:gst_base_transform_setcaps:<videorate0> transform 
    could not transform 
video/x-raw(memory:GLMemory), format=(string)RGBA, width=(int)800, height=(int)448, interlace-mode=(string)progressive, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, colorimetry=(string)sRGB, framerate=(fraction)30/1 
    in anything we support
```

Any ideas what is the issue here?

Thanks for any suggestions/help mates!

Comment: Does the pipe with run with gst-launch?

Comment: And also try putting `videoconvert` everywhere.

Comment: yes it does run with gst-launch

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem by replacing the source code of "cap_gstreamer.cpp" with the 3.2 version... i assume there is some bug in the 3.1 version... i did a diff of the 3.1 and 3.2 and couldnt really tell where the bug is...